# Regex math strings starting with @ and ending with with case insensitive string "goat"

Tags: regex

I wan to match all strings in a text that are between `@` and end with case insensitive `goat` but not match the string if there is a space in between.

https://regex101.com/r/gR1RjX/1

I have come up with this:

```
(?<=@)(.*)(?i)(goat)
```

But the problem it matches only the first occurrence and matches the space too.

Comment: If you don't want space, use `[^ ]*` instead of `.*`; alternately, write down the set of characters you *do* want to match, which will avoid further surprises with unwanted matching of unexpected characters

Comment: Try [`(?<=@)([^\s@]*?)(?i)(goat)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/YMGmup/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?i)(?<=@)([^\s@]*?)goat
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WirN3Q/1). If `goat` must be a whole word, do not forget a word boundary:

```
(?i)(?<=@)([^\s@]*?)goat\b
```

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `(?<=@)` - immediately on the left, there must be a `@` char
- `([^\s@]*?)` - Group 1: zero or more (but as few as possible) chars other than whitespace and `@`
- `goat\b` - a whole word `goat`.